# The nature of the symbol $\in$ in models of set theory within set theory

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I’ve been reading the basics on model theory from Kunen’s *Set Theory*, and have a few questions of the foundational kind. If at any point I do not make myself clear, I’ll try to elaborate to the best of my capacity,

One can construct model theory within ZFC: given a set of symbols $\mathcal{L}$ (partitioned into functions and relations by arity), we can recursively construct the set of well formed formulas as a certain subset of $(\mathcal{W}\cup \mathcal{L})^{<\omega}$, where $\mathcal{W}$ is the set of logical symbols (connectives, $=$, quantifiers, etc), which can be taken to be some subset of the natural numbers (the actual choice is irrelevant). Then, one defines a $\mathcal{L}$-structure as a pair $\mathfrak{A}=(A,\mathcal{I})$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is a map which assigns to each symbol in $\mathcal{L}$ a semantic entity in $A$ of the corresponding type (for instance, if $f\mathcal{L}$ is an $n$-ary function symbol, then $\mathcal{I}(f)=f^\mathfrak{A}:A^n\to A$). We can then use this framework to study different first order theories, such as rings, groups, etc. I start to have doubts when one tries to apply this to study models of set theory itself, which gives us a coding of the formulas of set theory (written in $\{\in\}$), which are objects of the meta theory, within ZFC, as actual sets. However, what is the set of symbols for this coding? Intuitively, its $\{\in\}$, but $\in$ is not an object of ZFC (not a set), but rather a logical symbol. So, what’s going on? I guess we could just define $\in$ to be some arbitrary set $t$ and then consider the formulas written in the language $\{t\}$ and then adequately interpreting everything, but can’t this approach run into some issues regarding unique readability?

On a related note, I see no problem with the actual models of set theory, one can just define a $\in$-model as a pair $(A,E_A)$ with $E_A:=\{(a,b)\in A\times A:a\in b\}$, but to write $(A,E_A)\models \phi$ for a coded formula of set theory $\phi$, one needs to know the language the coding is written in.

Comment: As long as you distinguish between $\in$ of the meta-theory and that of the model, there is no real issue. As you said, for other languages "the actual choice is irrelevant". And with some experience it is usually easy to make this distinction (not to mention, we often care about transitive models, where $E$ is *literally* $\in\restriction_{M\times M}$, which is what you denoted by $E_M$).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thank you for your comment. The difference between metamathematical $\in$ (the marking on the paper, if you will) and the membership relation of the given model is clear in my mind (or at least I think it is). Even though the choice of the language is irrelevant, when one goes to code the sentences of ZFC within ZFC (i.e. as sets), we do have to make a choice for the symbol $\in$, or am I mistaken? Obviously, we do not do this in practice, but shouldn't we know we can do it to talk about the coding. Also,to clarify, your last comment follows by absoluteness of $\in$, right?

Comment: We have to make a choice for the symbol $\in$, just as we have to make a choice for all the logical symbols of first-order logic (the $\mathcal W$ in your question) and the symbols of a vocabulary (the $\mathcal L$ in your question). $\in$ causes no more difficulty in this respect than any relation symbol in any other $\mathcal L$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Great, thank you!